# How to fit in IO type when using external libraries

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I'm trying out Hakyll and having trouble fitting in IO type into Hakyll compilation process. Here's an example Hakyll code from tutorial.

```
main :: IO ()
main = hakyll $ do
    match "posts/*" $ do
        route $ setExtension "html"
        compile $ do
            let url = -- $1
                ctx = stringField "title" url `mappend` defaultCtx
                in
                pandocCompiler
                >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" ctx
                >>= relativizeUrls
```

I want to look at the list of localized files (en.md, fr.md, ...) in matched directories and produce a list of available languages, which I will use to generate urls for redirecting to translations. I think this logic will have to be placed around `$1`.

It's file operation so it produces `IO [FilePath]`. But `$1` is inside `Hakyll.Compiler` monad, which is computed inside `Hakyll.Rules` and `IO` monads. Somehow I need to deal with `IO` type to work within the type signatures set by the library author. What is a good way to do this?

There are a few other implementations I can think of that avoid accessing file system and producing `IO` type, but I want to do it this way if possible. Plus, I want to get down to the bottom of this as it looks like a kind of issue that I may face commonly while writing Haskell.

Comment: does `Compiler`/`Rules` have `MonadIO` instances? maybe you could just lift them

Comment: sara There's `Compiler.unsafeCompiler :: IO a -> Compiler a` but I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be necessary to use `IO`, and that should generally be avoided because it prevents Hakyll from tracking dependencies.

There is a [`loadAll`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.12.4.0/docs/Hakyll-Core-Compiler.html#v:loadAll) function to get all items matching a pattern (in your case, possibly `"posts/currentpost/*.md"`, that might need messing with `getResourceFilePath` to construct). Then given all those `Item` you can look at their `itemIdentifier` and extract the basenames/languages (`fr`, `en`...).

```
-- rough sketch

...
  compile $ do
    currentPath <- getResourceFilePath
    allItems <- loadAll ... :: Compiler [Item ()]  -- () ignores the contents
    let idens = map itemIdentifier allItems
        url = ... idens
    ...
```

Comment: It almost worked... but Hakyll found circular dependency and refused to compile. When the initial matched item is `posts/quor/en.md`, `loadAll post/quor/*` ends up trying to load `posts/quor/en.md` again within the context of compiling the same file, causing circular dependency. This is a bit frustrating